# Swift compiler error after upgrade xcode 6 beta 6 to xcode 6 GM seed

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I was using xcode 6 beta 6, but I have installed xcode 6 GM seed. Then, I have faced a problem like **Swift Compiler error** **"Command/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1"**. I have researched many times and I have tried all of it but I couldnt find the solution. I have been using Alamofire library. I have uncomment code lines related to alamofire and delete from project directory and re-added it. Also, In some developer forums people mostly say that under the **project target and Build settings** - and clean **runpath search paths** and **framework search paths**. I have tried all of it but it is not compiled.

Thank you for your helps..

Best regards

Comment: Try a build folder clean (command-option-shift-K)

Comment: I have tried it now, but still same. I realized that when I go to derived data location from "Xcode-preferences", derived data folder occurs under Library folder. However, when I try to go to same location from desktop, I can not see Library file. Is it a problem ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I solved the problem as you say, in the first time, there is an error in the code block of a class. But xcode didnt warn me about it. I commented that block and I made "command+option+shift+K" and it worked. Thank you again @rmaddy :)

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I was implicitly unwrapping an optional in an Array in a for loop. Changing the ! to ? for the class of the iterating var fixed it.